# System.NoAccessException: Script-thrown exception while UserManagement.verifyPasswordlessLogin

Tags: apex, customer-community, login, login-errors, loginflow

community.

We are implementing Passwordless Login in Lightning community.
While we receive verification code on email, and verify it with following piece of code

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String SendCode(String code, String username, String identifier, String method){ 

        PageReference target;
        Auth.VerificationResult res;
        try {
        if(username != null){
            List<User> users = getUserByUsername(username); //simple method with SOQL that retrieves User by Username
            if(users != null && users.size() > 0){
                if(method == 'email'){
                     res = UserManagement.verifyPasswordlessLogin(users[0].Id, Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL, identifier, code, null); // the code fails on this line
                }else if(method == 'phone'){
                    res = UserManagement.verifyPasswordlessLogin(users[0].Id, Auth.VerificationMethod.SMS, identifier, code, null);
               }
                if(res.success){
                    target = Page.CommunitiesLanding;
                    target.setRedirect(true);
                    aura.redirect(target);
                }else{
                    return 'error';
                }
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('ex: ' + ex);
        }
        return '';
     }
```

The code fails with following exception:

```
09:02:35.0 (16885931)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[194]|ex|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Script-thrown exception"|0x258d8415
[...]
09:02:35.0 (16998696)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[195]|Bytes:53
USER_DEBUG|[195]|DEBUG| ex: System.NoAccessException: Script-thrown exception
```

I wonder what can be an issue? I assume it is something with session settings or community administration.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the user name same as email? We have implemented password less login recently but didn't had this issue. Also, can you confirm that initPasswordlessLogin called before works fine

Comment: The user name is not the same as email, though email is unique Salesforce recommend. InitPasswordlessLogin works fine and we successfully receive the verification code.

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved?

Comment: No, I created a case. It is not resolved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. We had an issue in our implementation. By some mistake the method was invoked with blank `identifier`, which caused to fail `UserManagement.verifyPasswordlessLogin` with this exception.

So, if someone else bumps into this exception, double check the value of `identifier`

Answer (score 0):

`Script thrown exception` hides the actual exception message, this happens for custom exception classes extending from `Exception`.

I suggest trying to use `ex.getMessage()` for your logs - it could provide more information than what we have so far.

Comment: I added stack trace and exception message:
`DEBUG| ex Stack: Class.System.UserManagement.verifyPasswordlessLogin: line 60, column 1
Class.Ctrl_LoginPage.SendCode: line 181, column 1
Message: Script-thrown exception` It seems like UserManagement throws this mysterious exception :(

Comment: That was what I feared. From here, you will need to open a case probably. I will ask around to see if somebody knows more.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely create a case